How do I select the date from a column that corresponds to the maximum value in another?
I have a workbook (Microsoft Excel for Mac, Version 16.16.27). In one column (B) I have dates which increase as the rows go down. In the next column (C) I have values.
In a row under both columns I show the maximum value from column C:
=MAX(C2:C13)

How do I select the date from column B that corresponds to the maximum value?
I've tried:
=MATCH(MAX(C2:C13,B:B,0)

It's not right.

You need INDEX()/MATCH() combination. Try-
=INDEX(B:B,MATCH(MAX(C:C),C:C,0))

